# Alternatives to Dictionary in Python - Need to reference value by named key and iterate in insertion order

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I am using Python and Django and messing around with returning JSON objects as Python dictonaries, but am not content because I can't iterate through my dictionary's elements in the order they were inserted.

If I create a dictionary as follows:

```
measurements = {
  'units': 'imperial',
  'fit': request.POST[ 'fit' ],
  'height': request.POST[ 'height' ],
  'weight': request.POST[ 'weight' ],
  'neck': request.POST[ 'neck' ],
  # further elements omitted for brevity
}
```

I can try iterating through it like:

```
for k,v in measurements.iteritems():
  print k, 'corresponds to ', v
```

The result is:

```
shoulders corresponds to  shoulders_val
weight corresponds to  weight_val
height corresponds to  height_val
wrist corresponds to  wrist_val
...
```

I also tried using sorted(), which iterates through my elements by key alphabetically

```
bicep corresponds to  bicep_val
chest corresponds to  chest_val
fit corresponds to  fit_val
height corresponds to  height_val
...
```

I am new to Python. I am hoping to find some way to both reference my dictionary elements by named keys like measurements['units'] but still be able to iterate through these elements in the order they were created. I am aware that there is an [ordered dictionary module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) out there, but I would like to stay away from nonstandard packages. Would any other standard Python data structures ( lists, arrays, etc. ) allow me to iterate in insertion order and reference values by named keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to preserve insertion order if you're using py2.7 or newer.  **This is a part of the standard library**.  For older versions, there's an [activestate recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) floating around that you could copy and use as part of your package/module.  Otherwise, there's nothing in the standard library that will do it.

You could subclass `dict` yourself and make it so the it remembers the order things were inserted -- storing the information in a list for instance -- but that is overkill when something already exists in the standard library for newer versions and a recipe that you can copy/paste is readily available if you want to support old versions.

---

Note that dictionary methods which accept dictionaries (`__init__`, `update`) won't be sorted properly if you pass dictionaries to them:

```
import collections
dd = collections.OrderedDict({
  'units': 'imperial',
  'fit': 'fit' ,
  'height': [ 'height' ],
  'weight': [ 'weight' ],
  'neck': [ 'neck' ],
})

print( dd )  #Order not preserved


#Pass an iterable of 2-tuples to preserve order.
ddd = collections.OrderedDict([
  ('units', 'imperial'),
  ('fit', 'fit') ,
  ('height', [ 'height' ]),
  ('weight', [ 'weight' ]),
  ('neck', [ 'neck' ]),
])

print( ddd ) #Order preserved
```

Answer (score 5):

`OrderedDict` is in the `collections` module, which is very much part of the core Python distribution (at least, as mgilson points out, in 2.7+).

OrderedDict is available by default in CPython 2.7, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3.  It is not present in 2.5, 2.6 or 3.0.